# SQL: Numbering rows based on logical test

Tags: sql

I have a VBA script that numbers rows incrementally in a csv file based on the date & time rows (the file is sorted by Date then Time) and I want to convert to an SQL script so I can number the rows directly in the database instead, I have no idea where to start though.

The VBA script starts at the beginning and if the date and time columns are the same assigns all of the rows the same id number, then when the date or time changes it increments the number and so on:

```
Private Sub eventID()

Dim event As Integer
event = 0

For i = 2 To 112543
If (Sheet1.Cells.Item(i, 2) = Sheet1.Cells.Item(i - 1, 2)) And (Sheet1.Cells.Item(i, 3) =   Sheet1.Cells.Item(i - 1, 3)) Then
Sheet1.Cells.Item(i, 1) = event
Else
event = event + 1
Sheet1.Cells.Item(i, 1) = event
End If
Next i    
End Sub
```

How can I do this in SQL Server 2012?
I have only 1 table and the eventID column is currently empty (NULL) waiting to be filled in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to load the data into a table that has `eventID` declared as an `identity` column.  This will automatically increment the values as new data is put in.

If this is not possible, you can do an update such as the following:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by date, time) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set EventId = seqnum;
```

EDIT:

If the date/time are the same and you want the same number, then use `dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by date, time) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set EventId = seqnum;
```

Comment: Thanks, it increments after each row though, I need it to only increment if the date or the time are different to the previous row. Basically, if the date and time are the same, it needs to have the same ID.

Comment: Excellent, dense_rank does the job. Cheers!